# conditional updateMany in MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I'm attempting to do a conditional update on all documents with a "Song Rating" greater than 9 in PyMongo. If the above condition is met, I want to add a condition to the document called "is_hit_song" and set its value to True.

```
collection.updateMany(
{'Song Rating': { '$gt': 9 }}, 
{'$set': {'is_hit_song': True}}, upsert=False, array_filters=None)
```

This is what I have tried, but I can't seem to execute the update because I get the error below.

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-110-2c2bc2715e77> in <module>()
      3 collection.updateMany(
      4     {'Song Rating': { '$gt': 9 }},
----> 5     {'$set': {'is_hit_song': True}},  upsert=False, array_filters=None)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pymongo/collection.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
   3319                         "call the '%s' method on a 'Collection' object it is "
   3320                         "failing because no such method exists." %
-> 3321                         self.__name.split(".")[-1])

TypeError: 'Collection' object is not callable. If you meant to call the 'updateMany' method on a 'Collection' object it is failing because no such method exists.
```

Can anyone help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

In pymongo the method is named `update_many()`

see an example [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_mongodb_update.asp)